# PHP in CLI Environment Making a SOAP Call, Error Fetching Headers

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Contacting a local `WSDL` file, I do this:

**PHP**

```
ini_set('max_input_time', -1);


$url = './APIService.wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient ($url);
```

The request is being properly, but when running `php file.php`, I get the following error:
**Error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in /Users/david/wsdl.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://aniweb02...', '', 1, 0)
#1 /Users/david/wsdl.php(16): SoapClient->__soapCall('searchNumbers', Array)
#2 {main}
```

Looking around, I've seen many recommendations like `ini_set('max_input_time', -1);` and other timeout settings; I'm worried that this is failing because I'm using a CLI PHP client instead of a traditional web request.

Comment: what makes you think input time has anything to do with that error? It says NOTHING about "timed out". did you check if the api endpoint you're hitting is actually reachable?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely reachable and identical requests work fine in SoapUI. I bring up input time, because 12 of the first 15 Google searches cite these sorts of issues as the cause.